# in Dask method from_delayed returns a scalar instead of dataframe

Tags: dask-dataframe, dask-delayed

I have a following problem - I have a list of delayed objects after applying following code (see below):

When I am applying

`ddf = dd.from_delayed(lazy_results_names)`

instead of dask dataframe I recieve dask scalar. For some reason this method returns a scalar.

Can you please help me how can update the code so that instead I recieve a dataframe? I have tried reading documentation and Chat GPT, both don't help much.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.delayed

from dask import delayed, compute
from fuzzywuzzy import process

#first dask dataset
data_orbis = {'Name': ['Johanna', 'Chanti', 'Pamela', 'Connie', 'Cesar', 'Eldar', 'Chris', "Richard","Rechard","Carl","Carl"],'ID': ['100', "200","300","400","500","600","700", "800", "900", "999", "1100" ], 'Country': ["Germany", "Germany", "Czechia","Russia","Andorra","France","Germany","Germany","Germany", "Denmark", "Sweden" ], 'City': ["Mainz", "Mainz", "Brno", "Moscow", "Andorra","Paris", "Berlin", "Mainz", "Mannheim","Copenhagen", "Malmo" ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_orbis)

dask_df_orbis = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)
name_series_orbis = dask_df_orbis["Name"]

#second dask dataset

data_dealscan = {'Name': ['Andrey', 'Canti', 'Pamelo', 'Cannie', 'Cezar', 'Eltor', 'Chriss', "Richard", "Rechard","Carl","Carll"],'ID': ['np.nan', "np.nan","np.nan","np.nan","500","600","700", "800","900", "999", "np.nan"], 'Country': ["Germany", "Germany", "Czechia","Russia","Andorra","France","Germany","Germany","Germany","Denmark", "Sweden"], 'City': ["Mainz", "Mainz", "Brno", "Moscow", "Andorra","Paris", "Berlin", "Mainz", "Mannheim","Copenhagen", "Malmo"  ]}
pandas_df_dealscan = pd.DataFrame(data_dealscan)
dask_df_dealscan = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df_dealscan, npartitions=4)
dask_series_dealscan_names = dask_df_dealscan['Name']


# Convert Dask Series to Dask list using delayed
@delayed(nout=100)
def series_to_list(series):
    return series.tolist()

# Apply the delayed function to the Dask Series
dask_dealscan_names_list = series_to_list(dask_series_dealscan_names)

# Define a delayed function for matching
@dask.delayed
def match_names_with_country_and_city(name_dealscan, country, city, name_series_orbis):
    best_match = process.extractOne(name_dealscan, name_series_orbis)
    best_match = best_match[0]  # Extracting the best match from the tuple
    return best_match

# Create a list of delayed computations
lazy_results_names = []
for name_dealscan, country, city in zip(dask_dealscan_names_list, dask_df_dealscan['Country'], dask_df_dealscan['City']):
    # Delay the computation of matching function
    lazy_result_name = match_names_with_country_and_city(name_dealscan, country, city, name_series_orbis)
    lazy_results_names.append(lazy_result_name)
```

Comment: Are your delayed objects Pandas Dataframe?